# Changing the visual properties of the mesh

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics, geometry, google-project-tango

Is it possible to give the mesh transparency (glass like properties) while maintaining the planar angles of the polyhedral?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with this questions. The coloring of the geometry shouldn't change any of the vertices or triangles. Could you elaborate more on the question

Comment: I would like to put a layer of video uniformly scaled to the respective vertices.  I would need the mesh to have a similar light reflection to that of glass to achieve the desired effect.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is more like a computer graphic question, you might want to tag the computer-graphic tag with the question. From Tango perspective, the API give you a textureID which is sufficient for such kind of operation on shader.